# Excel File Size Close to 300MB

Tags: excel

I have an excel file close to 300MB. There are a few tabs and are all text based. 
All fonts are the same. Some are characters and some are date formats. one tab is close to 1M row now. But the number of columns in all tabs are only less than 30. No macros included or links to other files.

I read that Excel limit is ~1M rows X 2000 columns. Does that mean as long as my columns are less than 30, then this file can still potentially grow? Or would it just stop running once it reaches 1M?

thanks in advance.

Comment: SaveAs xlsb (excel binary).

Comment: The max number of rows is 1,048,576.  That is regardless of the number of columns.  The number of columns is 16384.  That is regardless in the number of rows.  Just because the overall number of cells is less than 1,048,576 * 16384 does not mean you can have more rows or columns than the extents allowed.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have 2^20 (1048576) rows you will not be able to add a new row. In order to understand this, select range **A1** and keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd> until you see the last row. Once you reach it, you cannot go further.

Concerning the 1.000.000+ entries and the need for more rows - it seems that you are using Excel as a database, and it is really not a good idea to use it as one. If you need so many entries, you probably need a nice database, which would be fast and easy. MS Access (as far as you are using Excel, this is the db with most similar interface) can solve your solution easily. Or MS SQL Server.